# Is there any python web framework doesn't require url mapping?

Tags: python, codeigniter, url-mapping

I like the way php codeigniter provide, What you need is a controller class with an action function, then you can navigate to **domain.com/controller_name/action_name**.
no explicit mapping.

Answer (score 0):

check out django https://www.djangoproject.com/
 but it is not 100% the same as codeigniter
because each frame work has its own functionality and usage.

Comment: I know some python frameworks, just don't like mapping url explicitly